# Is there a clear algorithm for sorting/ordering the loops in an X12 file?

Tags: edi, x12

Even though loops are kind of a logical concept in X12 (not directly physically represented in the text), every transaction set defines a set of loops that it can contain, including identifiers for the loops and an ordering for them. My question is, what is the rule for sorting loops, generically? Is there a concise set of rules that can be expressed in some code that should be able to take a collection of loops (with known identifiers such as 1000A, 2300BB, etc) and properly sort them?

The context of my question is that I'm working on a general-purpose library that applications will use to construct a model of an X12 document/transaction-set (and write out the text such a model represents). It has objects to represent Elements, Segments, and Loops. Ordering of Segments in a particular Loop is easy, they're dictated by the Implementation Guides. But I'm trying to get Loop ordering (within a Transaction Set) to work generically; that's what I'm asking about

It seems that the general rule is that Loops are ordered based on their identifiers using the numeric portion as the primary sort key, with the alpha portion as the secondary sort key. Of course hierarchical loops contained in others will be placed before and loops following the parent in that sort order (eg: 1000A, 2000A, 2010A, 2010B, 2100, 2300 - where 2010A and 2010B are children of 2000A).

I understand that the spec and Implementation Guides contain all of this info; I'm looking for the all-encompassing rule about loop ordering (**not** Segment ordering). Is there any concise way to express the rule algorithmically? Is there even a hard-and-fast rule at all?

Comment: I guess you are talking about x12 837 ?

Comment: @eppye : Not necessarily, although that *is* the kind of document I'm dealing with currently. I'd like to have answers that apply to any X12 transaction sets.

Comment: actually it is a bit hard to tell what you are asking. try to explain.

Comment: The ANSI X12 standard is defined by a dictionary where the segments are listed in a specific order.  These segments have a particular loop value.  You would need to read the dictionary and determine how many times that particular segment can repeat.  You should look into this product: http://liaison.com/products/integrate/edi-notepad ($249) to get a solid picture of what the dictionary looks like and how to code around it.

Comment: I added some more context, hopefully that clarifies why and what I'm asking.

Comment: I think I'm more confused now.  I don't think there is a hard and fast rule. The segments have an order and loop value.  If a child segment can loop 100 times, as long as it is contained within the parent segment, it is valid.  The elements that act as qualifiers can be in an arbitrary order defined by each partner (N101, for example) in each iteration of the N1.

Comment: @Andrew, forget everything about segments and elements. Assume I already have segments ordered and repeated correctly within each individual loop. Now I have a bag of loops (each made up of segments) and I want to make sure they are written out in the correct order according to the Transaction Set I'm currently building.

Comment: the 'loops' that you are talking about are just a way of documenting certain (more complex) transactions. Nothing more, nothing less. The names are quite arbitrary. If you can detect an algorithm: do not implement it. Next release this might not be true anymore.

Comment: I've moved on from the X12 world, but IIRC I ended up using the policy I outlined in the 3rd paragraph in my question,basically using numeric part of the loop identifier as primary sort key and the alpha part as secondary. I had to write a custom Comparator (that project was in Java) for my Identifier class, but it was pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comments, the standard has a loop value.  Take a look at my screenshot of the Liaison Dictionary Viewer.  The CLM segment has a LOOP value of 100.  The segments underneath are children of the CLM segment (extended tag).  Any "order" can be defined arbitrarily by the partner, or can be in any (undefined) order provided the data is qualified.  But that loop can occur 100 times max and can have repeating segments inside the loop value.

The implementation guide will give you the correct order your partner wants them in.  It seems like you're writing your own syntax validation engine though.

[image]